# How to hide internal module only exports from module users and cosumers?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am writing few node packages using ES Modules. There are modules that are supposed to be external (i.e. used by external packages) while certain module exports are specifically internal to my package.

As far as I know, there is no way to signify certain modules as internal only in ES modules. But is there any standard practice/guidelines followed while developing node packages to deter users from using internal only modules?

The reason I need this is that my packages are written in TypeScript and TypeScript generates declaration files automatically which also include exports for internally intended modules.

Comment: Only provide documentation for external modules? That tends to be a good indicator of what parts of your package are expected to remain stable, while your internal modules, without supporting documentation, are free to change implementations between versions.